# Rspec - PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "application" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to start building out and running my rspec tests using `bin rails\test`. They used to work a while ago, but now when I run them i'm getting the error below for every single test.

```
Error:
VenueTest#test_should_not_save_venue_without_name:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "application" does not exist
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "application"
                    ^
: DELETE FROM "application"

Finished in 0.382377s, 41.8435 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
16 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 16 errors, 0 skips
```

I've barely written any tests, so it's just the pre-rolled ones that are now failing.

I've tried running the migrations (which run fine) and the test db is definitely created. I've also tried:

```
rake db:test:prepare
rake db:test:load
```

but still getting the same error. I also don't have a model named 'application', so no idea why it's trying to delete from "application"?

I'm guessing this is some sort of weird config thing that i've messed up somewhere along the way, but have no idea what it could be!

All tests are failing, but the tests in question are:

Home_Controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class HomeControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should get index" do
    get home_index_url
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

offers_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class OffersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @offer = offers(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get offers_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get new_offer_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create offer" do
    assert_difference('Offer.count') do
      post offers_url, params: { offer: { desc: @offer.desc, end: @offer.end, offertype: @offer.offertype, start: @offer.start } }
    end

    assert_redirected_to offer_url(Offer.last)
  end

  test "should show offer" do
    get offer_url(@offer)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get edit_offer_url(@offer)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update offer" do
    patch offer_url(@offer), params: { offer: { desc: @offer.desc, end: @offer.end, offertype: @offer.offertype, start: @offer.start } }
    assert_redirected_to offer_url(@offer)
  end

  test "should destroy offer" do
    assert_difference('Offer.count', -1) do
      delete offer_url(@offer)
    end

    assert_redirected_to offers_url
  end
end
```

venues_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class VenuesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @venue = venues(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get venues_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get new_venue_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create venue" do
    assert_difference('Venue.count') do
      post venues_url, params: { venue: { desc: @venue.desc, exists: @venue.exists, latitude: @venue.latitude, longitude: @venue.longitude, name: @venue.name, region: @venue.region, vtype: @venue.vtype } }
    end

    assert_redirected_to venue_url(Venue.last)
  end

  test "should show venue" do
    get venue_url(@venue)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get edit_venue_url(@venue)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update venue" do
    patch venue_url(@venue), params: { venue: { desc: @venue.desc, exists: @venue.exists, latitude: @venue.latitude, longitude: @venue.longitude, name: @venue.name, region: @venue.region, vtype: @venue.vtype } }
    assert_redirected_to venue_url(@venue)
  end

  test "should destroy venue" do
    assert_difference('Venue.count', -1) do
      delete venue_url(@venue)
    end

    assert_redirected_to venues_url
  end
end
```

EDIT

Stacktrace below as requested:

bin/rails test test/controllers/offers_controller_test.rb:18

```
E

Error:
VenueTest#test_should_not_save_venue_without_name:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "application" does not exist
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "application"
                    ^
: DELETE FROM "application"
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:614:in `async_exec'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in exec_no_cache'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:46:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:185:in `yield_shares'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:45:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:613:in `block in exec_no_cache'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in log'
    /Users/James/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:611:in `block in log'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:603:in `log'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:612:in `exec_no_cache'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:599:in `execute_and_clear'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:92:in `exec_delete'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:145:in `delete'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:17:in `delete'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:546:in `block (4 levels) in create_fixtures'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:544:in `each_key'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:544:in `block (3 levels) in create_fixtures'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:540:in `each'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:540:in `block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:235:in `block in transaction'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:194:in `block in within_new_transaction'
    /Users/James/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:191:in `within_new_transaction'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:235:in `transaction'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:538:in `block in create_fixtures'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/referential_integrity.rb:22:in `disable_referential_integrity'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:523:in `create_fixtures'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:1028:in `load_fixtures'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:965:in `setup_fixtures'
    /Users/James/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:851:in `before_setup'
```

EDIT - added Venue_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class VenueTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end

  test "should not save venue without name" do
    venue = Venue.new
    assert_not venue.save, "Saved the venue without a title"
  end


end
```

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace?

Comment: Hi @GuyYogev, thanks for the reply. I've added the backtrace above. :-)

Comment: Could you please share the test in question?

Comment: Hi @dskecse i've added in the scripts. They were all working previously, so not sure it's test script related.

Comment: have you tried running with the **RAILS_ENV=test** flag.  `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:test:prepare
&& rake db:test:load`

Comment: Yep, i've just re-run again to be sure but still seeing the same issue

Comment: The error clearly states that the problem is with the unit test `VenueTest`, not functional (i.e. controller) tests, so could you share it as well?

Comment: Shared venue_test.rb - apologies, was looking at the `VenueTest#test_should_not_save_venue_without_name: ` line

Comment: The Rails generator might have created files in the `test/fixtures/` directory that don’t correspond to any actual tables in your database. Could you please double-check them?

Comment: Hmm.. I've run the tests before and they were ok, wouldn't expect them all to fail now based on the changes i've made. Just re-checked and they look ok. It's weird it's coming up with `PG::UndefinedTable` error, do you know where the table is referenced?

Comment: @JamesOsborn the table is probably referenced from a file in the `test/fixtures/` directory

Comment: @dskecse Should there be anything in the application.yml? It's currently blank.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158054/discussion-between-dskecse-and-james-osborn).

Answer (score 3):

Running below command fixed this error for me:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:test:prepare
```

Thanks @guy-yogev

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else is seeing this issue, there were extra files in the test/fixtures folder (maybe created by the generator). @dskecse identified the issue.

Once these are removed scripts run fine.